# LDAP Server Acting As CRM

Tags: java, ldap, crm, ldif

I am currently working on development of a CRM product for my company. LDAP is used access information about:

- User information
- Contact information
- Network resources

LDAP can be used to lookup:

- Encryption certificates
- Pointers to printers
- Services
- Access same directory from various services

I am currently building the architecture of this CRM platform. Is it common to use LDAP as a CRM Repository? Is it a good idea to store customer information in LDAP in the context?

As an example, the software will have customers, products, orders.

I am trying to look for some examples of architectures, but can't seem to find the architecture used on most CRM systems.

I hope you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP is best suited to store data about users - it's a directory. Though it can be used to store pretty much anything, I would certainly not choose LDAP as a data store for a CRM.

Have you looked at http://www.sugarcrm.com/? You can still use your LDAP directory to authenticate users and perform lookups.

Comment: Thanks. Is it a good idea to store customer information in LDAP?

Comment: @user1646481 Yes, as long as you only need the attributes provided by your LDAP schema (phone number, email etc). Extending it is not as easy as adding columns to a database. Nothing's keeping you from grabbing the user's record from LDAP upon login and using it to populate your database tables. This is how most LDAP-aware applications function.